# Second largest bid in auction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to produce a report which shows the second highest bidders for various auctions.  Sample data for a single auction is included below.  How might I write a query to return:

- The `AuctionID`.
- The second highest bid.
- The time difference between the highest bid and second highest bid.

```
AuctionID   BidAmount   BidDate             UserID
15410       42559.23    16/11/2012 19:38    41
15410       23613.12    16/11/2012 19:16    2
15410       18000.00    16/11/2012 19:13    16
15410       15249.94    16/11/2012 18:38    9
15410       9813.50     16/11/2012 18:36    7
15410       5341.58     16/11/2012 18:16    7
```

Comment: `Sql Server` version?

Comment: You should provide what you have tried so far. Otherwise it might appear as if you have not researched anything and just want us to write the query for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      AuctionID INT ,
      Amount MONEY ,
      BidDate DATETIME ,
      UserID INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 15410, 42559.23, '20121116 19:38', 41 ),
        ( 15410, 23613.12, '20121116 19:16', 2 ),
        ( 15410, 18000.00, '20121116 19:13', 16 ),
        ( 15410, 15249.94, '20121116 18:38', 9 ),
        ( 15410, 9813.50, '20121116 18:36', 7 ),
        ( 15410, 5341.58, '20121116 18:16', 7 );


WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY AuctionID ORDER BY Amount DESC ) AS rn
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  c1.AuctionID ,
            c2.Amount ,
            DATEDIFF(ss, c1.BidDate, c2.BidDate) DiffInSeconds
    FROM    cte c1
            JOIN cte c2 ON c2.AuctionID = c1.AuctionID
                           AND c1.rn = 1 AND c2.rn = 2
```

Output:

```
AuctionID   Amount   DiffInSeconds
15410       23613.12 -1320
```

Comment: Hi Giorgi..How you are able to get sample data so fast :)

Comment: @TheGameiswar, what do you mean? I had enough time to copy data from question and add some quotes and commas.

Comment: oh :) ,i tried answering the question by copying some data and pasting it here and using sql fiddle..http://tools.perceptus.ca/text-wiz.php

Comment: @TheGameiswar, there is http://sqlfiddle.com/ for you. But I have Sql Server installed, so no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL you can select the entry you wish with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BidAmount DESC) AS rownumber, <tablename>.*
  FROM <tablename>
)
WHERE rownumber = 2
```

Comment: I have more than one auctionid so this is not sufficient but if I modify yours as follows SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id ORDER BY value DESC) AS rownumber, Table_1.*
  FROM Table_1
) z
WHERE z.rownumber = 2 then it works